# Postgresql copy generated column

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

Let's assume a table `t`:

```
create table if not exists t(
    a integer primary key generated by default as identity,
    b integer,
    c text
);
```

and simple insert `insert into t (b, c) values (2, 'abc');`
Is there any option how to rewrite this insert and as a result in column `b` will be `coalesce(b, a)`?
So when `b` is `null`, `b` equals to generated column `a`.

I know there is an option to use `RETURNING` keyword and update or to use before insert trigger.

Comment: No:`insert into t (b, c) values (coalesce(null, a), 'abc'); HINT:  There is a column named "a" in table "t", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you intend to do introduces redundancy, so I recommend that you don't do it. Rather, use `coalesce` wjen you query the table. A convenient solution would be a view on the table that does that.

If you insist on persisting that in the table, you will have to use a trigger.